# How to properly manage multiple independent maven projects versioning in eclipse

Tags: java, maven, continuous-integration, maven-3, continuous-deployment

This may be an easy answer for you but I've been spending lot of my time changing the project versions. Here is my situation:

I have 8 java spring projects in my eclipse workspace. 5 projects depend on the 3 other libraries.If I change the versioning of any of the three projects [which is quite often], I need to change the versions all the 5 project pom.xml files. I found it very cumbersome. I tried changing the versioning of these 3 dependent projects to a constant value [e.g. latest], then my local set up is working fine but CI/CD doesn't change the next incremental version.

I'm pretty sure I'm not the only one who is facing this type of situation. Hoping someone can guide me on how to manage the versioning locally and in the CI/CD process.

Thank you for reading this!

Comment: Can you describe/show more in detail what you mean by: `If I change the versioning of any of the three projects [which is quite often], I need to change the versions all the 5 project pom.xml files` ???

Comment: project - you think of Maven module? Do you have one parent pom of all with `modules` tag?

Comment: Those are all independent projects, not having any parent pom. No modules whatsoever @SlawomirJaranowski

Comment: @khmarbaise I meant, if I change version of the projects (say project 1, project 2 or project 3), I would have to change the dependency of these projects everywhere they have been mentioned as dependency.

Comment: Do you use -SNAPSHOTs?

Comment: I'm not using Snapshot @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen. Wondering how would snapshot solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

1st solution: Put all eight projects into one multi-module project and build it together with the same version number

2nd solution: Do not change the versions so often, only if you publish everything as productive version to the outside world.